# Is there a phrase for "the boy who cried wolf" when the boy stops crying wolf because the townsfolk won't believe him anyway?

Tags: phrase-requests

In the Fable of "The Boy who cried Wolf", the townsfolk end up not believing the boy when there actually is a wolf because he lied about there being a wolf so many times, leading to the flock of sheep getting eaten.

Now, suppose the townsfolk stopped believing him way earlier, and the boy stopped crying wolf, even if there really is a wolf, because he knows the townfolk won't believe him anyway.

Is there a term/proverb that can be used to describe this boy? Maybe something from a different fable or a real world event?

Comment: The proverb is so well known that it has its own phrasal verb: "to cry wolf". Thus the noun phrase "a crier of wolf" and, hence, he would become known as a "**reformed crier of wolf**".

Comment: The 'crying wolf' parable is about false positives. the boy is telling lies to get a reaction from people, so eventually they learn to not trust him even when he's telling the truth. The nearest situation to that is Cassandra who always told the truth (about predicting bad things would happen), but no one believed her. So you may be able to rejigger your writing slightly to use 'Cassandra'.

Comment: What's the moral of the story you're looking for? Also check to see if this helps: [When someone ruins all the good they have ever done!](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/263319/191178)

Comment: @Mitch "The boy who cried Cassandra" or "the Cassandra who cried wolf"? :)

Comment: @Laurel The moral of the story: A person who has repeatedly been worried they're infected with something because of symptoms caused by unrelated circumstances (at least, not directly related to the thing they're worried about), but who later on decides to ignore their symptoms and not share their concerns with anyone because they assume everyone is going to say they're fine. Something like that in any case.

Comment: @Greybeard 'Crier of wolf' can hardly be called idiomatic (~2000 hits on Google), and 'reformed crier of wolf' gets 0 hits. Note that the tag OP selected requires idiomaticity (I've added 'phrase request', as not all fixed phrases qualify as idioms).

Comment: I think @Mitch has nailed it. In Anglophone culture, references to ***Cassandra*** (and the derived adjective ***Cassandrian***) normally allude to *speaking the truth, but not being believed*. It's a minor detail that the boy crying wolf directly caused his own "lack of credibility" by lying before, whereas Cassandra was afflicted by Apollo's *curse*. However they got into that position, their current circumstances are that nobody believes either of them.

Comment: @Laurel However, the boy who cried wolf hasn't done any good up to now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have no idea whether idiomaticity is what I'm after. To be frank, I don't even know what's so special about an idiom and couldn't tell from google either. I'm probably gonna edit that tag out, because it's probably the wrong one.

Comment: For word/phrase requests, it is helpful to have a sentence that demonstrates how you would like use the word or phrase.

Comment: 'Idiomaticity' has the default meaning, used on ELU, 'regularly used rather than rare'. An 'idiom' on the other hand has the default meaning 'a fixed expression in common use with the additional condition that one word or more, or grammar, or both are used in an unconventional way'. 'Cry wolf' is itself an idiom. I'll put the tag back in to allow idioms (eg 'you've made your bed, now lie in it') as well as transparent fixed expressions.

Comment: Not a picturesque term, so it’s not quite what you’re asking for, but the boy has been _discredited_ and is possibly _disheartened_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Idiom for the phrase "someone who gets what he deserved"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171544/idiom-for-the-phrase-someone-who-gets-what-he-deserved) 'His chickens have come home to roost' etc.

Comment: We would say: 'He ran out of lies.'

Comment: Is the boy asking himself, "What's the use in crying wolf?" (it's futile) or is the boy thinking "OK, let them learn the hard way"? (bitterness) And was he still the serial liar or did he just mistake a dog for a wolf one time, or something like that -- one honest mistake?

Comment: He's the boy who might as well not say anything.

Answer (score 0):

> ### you've made your bed, now lie in it
>
> [said to someone who must accept the unpleasant results of something
> they have done](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-ve-made-your-bed-now-lie-in-it) (*Cambridge Dictionary*)

The unpleasant results of repeatedly “crying wolf” gratuitously, is to be labelled an instigator and/or a liar.

- *Even though the boy stopped crying wolf by then it was too late, he'd made his bed and he had to lie in it*

The proverb is attributed to a phrase written by the 15th century French writer Guillaume Flamant in his book “La Vie et Passion de Monseigneur Sainct Didier, Martir et Evesque de Lengres” published in 1482.

'*[Comme on faict son lict, on le treuve](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Oxford_Dictionary_of_Proverbs/LMGPCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Comme%20on%20faict%20son%20lict,%20on%20le%20treuve%22&pg=PA198&printsec=frontcover)*' (As one makes one's bed, so one finds it).

Comment: I'm note sure whether by "a term/proverb that can be used to describe this boy" the OP means explain the boy's state of mind (why he has given up) or judge the boy.

Comment: @DjinTonic the idiom doesn't describe the boy but fits the description of the situation. Someone who used to lie but was believed compared to  the same individual now telling the truth but no longer believed. The boy's reputation soiled because once you've lost people's trust it is rare to earn it back.

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation of your senario is correct, when the townsfolk [finally] understood/realized what the wolf-crying boy was up to (just trying to get attention/reactions), they stopped reacting to/believing the boy and his cries, and the boy in turn [**"[finally] got the message"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20the%20message)  (that the townsfolk no longer believed him and would no longer react to his cries).

With this message in mind, the boy felt that continuing to cry wolf was useless and stopped crying wolf altogether, even when there was a wolf to cry about.

> **get the message** idiom
>
> Definition of *get the message*
>
> informal:
>
> to understand something that is not being said directly
>
> When they didn't return my phone calls, I finally *got the message*.

from:
Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, Accessed 4 Sep. 2022

Answer (score 0):

A *Non-credible witness*  In the classic case the boy is no longer a *credible witness*. He is justifiably if tragically ignored after too many trips to the well. Hungry wolves and other professionals have given some details on descriptions and remedies below.

https://legal-info.lawyers.com/criminal/criminal-law-basics/a-credible-witness-is-trustworthy-and-believable.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a phrase for "the boy who cried wolf" when the boy stops crying wolf because the townsfolk won't believe him anyway?

Normally, this would be "the **reformed*** boy who cried wolf." But **reformed** implies that he has forsaken **all** of his bad ways **because he realises they were wrong.**

In your example, the boy has not reformed as you say:

> the boy felt that continuing to cry wolf was useless and stopped crying wolf altogether,

This indicates that he still wished to be annoying (he is therefore not "reformed") but realised that crying wolf would not annoy anyone.

You therefore could describe him as "the **wiser**** boy who cried wolf" as he is now in possession of a useful piece of information but is not prohibited from being annoying in new ways.

*OED:

> **3. Of a person. 3.a. Improved in character or conduct; spec. having relinquished an immoral, criminal, or self-destructive lifestyle.**
>
> 1909 ‘Well, Anne's methods seem to have worked fairly well with Davy,’
> said Mrs. Lynde smilingly. ‘He's a reformed character.’
> *L. M. Montgomery, Anne of Avonlea xxvi. 306*

> **wise: 3.a. Having knowledge, well-informed; - [hence comparative "wiser" - Having **more** knowledge, **better**-informed
>
> 2024 "I did not understand your explanation, so I am not any wiser." (Greybeard EL&U)